# Scala Swing Date Picker

Tags: scala

Looking to convert Java Swing DatePicker into Scala but facing difficulty in one area of the code. How should I probably translate the if (x > 6) part into scala?

Original Java taken from http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/datePicker.html

```
for (int x = 0; x < button.length; x++) {
                    final int selection = x;
                    button[x] = new JButton();
                    button[x].setFocusPainted(false);
                    button[x].setBackground(Color.white);
                    if (x > 6)
                            button[x].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                                            day = button[selection].getActionCommand();
                                            d.dispose();
                                    }
                            });
                    if (x < 7) {
                            button[x].setText(header[x]);
                            button[x].setForeground(Color.red);
                    }
                    p1.add(button[x]);
            }
```

Converted Scala

```
for (x <- 0 until buttons.length) {
            val selection = x
            buttons(x) = new Button {
                focusPainted = false
                background = Color.white
            }
            if (x > 6)
                buttons(x).reactions += {
                    case ButtonClicked(_) => {
                        day = buttons(selection).action
                        d.dispose()
                    }
                }   
            if (x < 7) {
                buttons(x).text = header(x)
                buttons(x).foreground = Color.red
            }
            contents += buttons(x)
        }
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem with the presented translation? The more you do to help us help you, the more likely you are to get good help.

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with your translation? Is it not working? The only thing I can see *at a glance* is that you do not **listen** to the button:

```
button(x) listenTo button(x)
```

But I'm not sure how wise a button listening to itself is, or whether there are any nasty consequences. You don't *need* to add the reactions to the button itself, you could probably add them to the date picker itself.

Also, something like `zipWithIndex` is possibly preferable to the way you have done it:

```
buttons.zipWithIndex foreach { case (button, x) =>
    //no need to use buttons(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if(x < 7)` could be replaced by `else`, that would be clearer.

You could use a match statement as well:

```
x match {
    case xx if xx > 6 => ...   
    case _ => ...   
}
```